# Read lines accessing by number line

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a file and detect each time that a pattern is repeated :

```
-1
58
```

I want that each time that these two lines are repeated, a trigger starts a function. The problem is that I'm reading my file like that :

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath);

foreach (var line in lines)
{
   // CODE
}
```

So I'm capable of treating the text line. Is there a way to access the lines by ID indicating their position ?

Thank you !

Comment: [You can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__), but why? You only need to remember inside the loop whether `prev_value` is `"-1"`.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so have a boolean that remembers if the last line was -1:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath);

bool lastLineWasMinusOne = false;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
   if(lastLinesWasMinusOne && line == "58")
     //do your thing

   //the last thing we do before you move to the next line is remember whether this line is -1 or not
   lastLineWasMinusOne = (line == "-1");
}
```

If the file is small enough to read the whole thing into an array, life might be simpler by looking for `if(lines[i] == "58" && lines[i-1] == "-1")` using a normal `for` loop

Or it might be better to just read the file as a string and look for `"-1\r\n58"` (or similar, depending if your file is windows, unix, mac etc) though.. Perhaps even use it as a delimiter for splitting?

---

Edit:

From the comment you implied you might need something else on the line too (though the question implies that the line only contains -1 - if you oversimplified the question, perhaps take this as a pointer to consider not doing so next time) so you can keep the whole line:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath);

var lastLine = "";
foreach (var line in lines)
{
   if(lastLine == "-1" && line == "58")
     //do your thing

   //the last thing we do before you move to the next line is remember this line
   lastLine = line;
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that I cannot go backwards in any case. I mean, once I have, for example, read the line 506 I can never read again the line 505. If I would like to do so I would have to restart reading the wole file. Am I right ?

Comment: Er, sort of... You're right that you can't read backwards again but if you only need the previous line you just keep the whole line rather than just keeping a boolean

Comment: (If you need the last 5 lines then you can use e.g. a Queue or circular array to remember the last 5 lines.. If you need the last N lines but only since you saw a -1 and a 58, then the "do your thing" is "set a boolean capturing=true and if capturing, put lines into a list until you encounter the end delimiters.. )